# Usar dados do select em input

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tenho um código que seleciona uma opção dos dados que vem do banco de dados. Esta parte do código está ok, ele seleciona e traz.

O problema é que, ao selecionar este `option`, preciso preencher 4 campos `input` automaticamente, com dados que vem do banco.

Só consigo mostrar de um dado. Acredito que tenha que guardar estes dados para usar nos `inputs`, mas não sei como fazer.

Irei postar o código abaixo comentando:

```
<?php


    require_once('requerimentoController.class.php');
        $requerimento = new requerimentoController;
        $acervoGrid = $requerimento->gridAcervos();//Aqui recebo os dados do BD
        $qtdRow = count($acervoGrid);
?>
<html>
    <script>
    function selecionar(){
        document.getElementById('tipo').value = document.getElementById('selectOK').value;
    }
    </script>
    <body>
    <select id="selectOK" onchange="selecionar()">
        <?php for($a = '0'; $a < $qtdRow; $a++){ ?> 

    <option value="<?=$acervoGrid[$a]['tipo'];?>"><?php echo $acervoGrid[$a]['tipo']; ?>
    /* Aqui seleciono qual o valor que quero da tabela*/
    <?php }?>
    </select></br>
    <input type="text" id="tipo"/> /*aqui mostro no input os valores correspondentes ao que selecionei no option com dados que vem do banco.
    <input type="text" id="marca"/>
    <input type="text" id="serie"/>
    <input type="text" id="modelo"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, você vai precisar usar um javascript. Ao selecionar o  atuar nos inputs. Tenho um exemplo para você:

```
<script>
$('#selectOK').change(function (){
var e = document.getElementById('selectOK');
var strDocumento = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    if(strDocumento == "resultado1"){
        document.getElementById("tipo").value = "VALOR TIPO";
        document.getElementById("marca").value = "VALOR MARCA";
        /* etc..*/
    }
    if(strDocumento == "resultado2"){
        document.getElementById("tipo").value = "VALOR TIPO";
        document.getElementById("marca").value = "VALOR MARCA";
        /* etc..*/
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Gabriel, no caso eu preciso percorrer um array pra verificar quais campos e mostrar os mesmos.
Por exemplo, tenho no banco a coluna A B C e em cada coluna destas tenho dados tipo, marca serie.
Se eu selecionar a opçao B deveria mostrar nos input respectivo tipo, marca e serie.
Se for a opçao A, mesma coisa.